# Shared folders not working on VirtualBox with OS X host and windows guest

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to set up folder sharing on my windows guest OS with a OS X host, and somehow its not working.

Here’s my Shared folders in VirtualBox:

[image]

However, it does not show up in Windows automagically as it should.
I tried this command at terminal, looking at the VirtualBox [manual.](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

`net use x: \\vboxsvr\home`

only to be greeted with a “System error 53. The network path was not found.”

Oh oh, and creating a transient share from OS X works just fine, but again, Windows can’t seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Virtual Guest Additions** on your virtual machine, by selecting *Insert Guest Additions CD Image* from the *Devices* menu (on your running VM window). After that, shared folders should be available once your Windows machine is fully booted.

[image: Devices menu, Insert Guest Additions CD Image...]